# Coordinate Geometry: The locus of the mid point of normal chord of ellipse

Tags: analytic-geometry, conic-sections

> The locus of the mid point of normal chord of ellipse $$\frac{x^2}{a^2}+\frac{y^2}{b^2}=1$$
> (A)  $x^2+y^2=2$
>
> (B)  $x^2-y^2=1$
>
> (C)  $(\frac{a^6}{x^2}+\frac{b^6}{y^2})(\frac{x^2}{a^2}+\frac{y^2}{b^2})^2=(a^2-b^2)^2$
>
> (D)  $x^2+y^2=1$

**How I tried**

I can't type the rough work here because its huge, but the idea was to assume mid point of normal as $(h,k)$, then use $T=S_1$ to find equation of chord then solve the chord and ellipse to get point of contact, then find slope of tangent and slope of normal from that point and use $m_1m_2=-1$, but after few steps the calculation was among bi-quadratic, and very complex things that was very difficult to substitute.

The answer given is (C).

So my question is how would you solve the problem ? Is there a clean and easy way than my method mentioned above, so that I can use it in examination hall to get answer quickly.

Comment: What is normal chord?

Comment: @Aqua a normal chord is a normal only that intersects the ellipse at two points, one where its normal and the other may or may not be a normal

Comment: @Aqua I mean the question is to find locus of mid point of normal

Comment: @Aqua a line perpendicular to tangent at a point of ellipse, passing through the same point

Comment: Use the process of elimination: The principal axes are normal chords. Where is their midpoint? That will eliminate three of the possibilities immediately.

Answer (score 2):

Since it not a circle nor hyperbola it is c)

[image]